# Selenium program execution does not start using Python Class

Tags: python, selenium, class, selenium-webdriver, python-class

Here is the code

```
class InstogramBot():

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    def close_browser(self):
        self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
        time.sleep(5)
        name_input = self.driver.find_element_by_name("username")
        name_input.send_keys(username)
        time.sleep(2)
        password_input = self.driver.find_element_by_name("password")
        password_input.send_keys(password)
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]/button/div').click()
        time.sleep(7)
        self.driver.close()
        self.driver.quit()
```

Selenium doesn't show up and doesn't even open the web driver

Console snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Is that your whole code?/Did you instantiate this class? If you don't instantiate your class, no object will be created and no code will be run. You need to create the object and run the method you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you
show exactly how it should look?
I'm just a beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using *Python* you need to consider the following:

- Python being an object oriented programming language, everything in Python is represented as an object along with its properties and methods.
- A *Class* in Python is the object constructor i.e. the mechanism for creating the objects.

---

### Your program

The code block you have written includes the definition of the *Class* and the only *method*.

To initiate a successful execution, you need to create an instance, i.e an object of the class *`InstogramBot()`*

```
bot = InstogramBot("Рома", "Рома")
```

Finally, you need to invoke the method *`close_browser()`* through the object.

```
bot.close_browser()
```

---

### Solution

Your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

class InstogramBot():

    def __init__(self, username, password):
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def close_browser(self):
    self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
    time.sleep(5)
    name_input = self.driver.find_element_by_name("username")
    name_input.send_keys(username)
    time.sleep(2)
    password_input = self.driver.find_element_by_name("password")
    password_input.send_keys(password)
    time.sleep(2)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]/button/div').click()


bot = InstogramBot("Рома", "Рома")
bot.close_browser()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a driver object, this

```
self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
```

should result in a compile-time error.

**Fix :**

Please download latest chromedriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/)

```
Latest stable release: ChromeDriver 95.0.4638.54
```

Once downloaded, put that into some directory.

and use it like this :

```
driver_path = r'C:\\Users\\userID\\*****\\Desktop\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe'
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
```